# Как избежать состояния гонки в MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Мне нужно сделать двойной update в БД (чтобы обновилось или 2 item'a или ничего). Суть проблемы - после того как изменили первый объект,
в другом треде изменили второй объект, теперь в первом треде не можем изменить второй объект, потому что _etag(хеш-сумма состояния объекта) отличается.

[Two Phase Commits](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) - паттерн защищающий от race в Mongo, но как его интегрировать в мой код не понимаю.

Код:

```
    lookup = {'_id': req_profile_id, '_etag': req_profile_etag}
    res = patch_internal('profile', req_profile, concurrency_check=False, skip_validation=False, **lookup)  
    if res[0]['_status'] == 'ERR':
        return custom_response(500, 'Some error on patch req_profile')

    lookup = {'_id': profile_id, '_etag': profile_etag}
    res = patch_internal('profile', profile, concurrency_check=False, skip_validation=False, **lookup) 
    if res[0]['_status'] == 'ERR':
        return custom_response(500, 'Some error on patch profile')
```

`lookup` - содержит поля по которым выполняется поиск объекта в БД.

`patch_internal` - eve'вский update с автообновлением мета-полей (`_etag`, `_updated`) и активированием связных событий.

race condition может возникнуть между двумя `patch_internal`.

Comment: Вы не думали над тем, чтобы хранить объекты в памяти в каком-то месте (shared storage), доступном обоим потокам, и апдейтить в БД то отображение объекта, которое является последней его версией в shared storage?
Грубо говоря, сделать глобальный потокобезопасный кэш объектов, в котором можно будет обновлять объекты, а также на время блокировать их от модификации другими потоками.

Comment: Если по условиям задачи требовались транзакции, наверное лучшим выбором была бы БД с их поддержкой.